# How can I get the file path of a chosen file in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently creating an input in React by which a user can click on a button and open a browse box to select a file. The goal is to **find the file path of the chosen file**.

I'm aware that it is impossible to get the filepath from just a simple `<input type="file"/>` due to security reasons but I was wondering if there is a way to do it that I just haven't found or even a method in node that I could utilize by passing the file name to a node.js back end that could help me find the path.

I've also already looked into the fs-path npm package in node to find all paths and files so I could potentially match the file name to it's path but this doesn't help me if there is more than one file with the same name in a different path.

I can't seem to find any other suggestions except for just uploading the entire file's contents, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: what environment is this in? an electron app?

Comment: if it's just in a normal browser, I don't think you can get the path of a file.

Comment: I think it's a normal browser but would making it an electron app make any difference?

Comment: Yes, normal browsers do not have file system access. Electron apps (and even windows store apps, which you can do with html+css+js) do.

Comment: So if I make an application with Electron JS, then I should be able to get the file path using a <input type="file"/> tag?

Comment: Well I cannot vouch for the <input/> aspect, but I'm sure Electron apps do give you, in some way, more access to the files and the file system than a browser does. The `input` api might not be changed, but it's worth investigating if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had to be able to run my application in a normal browser, something like ElectronJS wasn't viable for me to use. What I ended up doing instead was creating a back-end in Node JS and sending a request to the node back end for all files in a predetermined directory. I then used `fs.readdir` to return all the files and directories in the file and displayed them on my front-end React Application after which I allowed the user to choose a file or a directory. If a file was chosen, then I had my file path since I already knew what the current directory was. If a directory was chosen, another request was sent to the same API to get the files and directory of the new directory.

```js
app.get('/api/fileFinder', async (req, res) => {
    const mainDir = req.query.name || '/efs/data';
    console.log(mainDir);
    fs.readdir(mainDir, function(err, items) {
        const dirs = [];
        const files = [];
        if (items){
            for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                if (fs.lstatSync(mainDir + '/' + items[i]).isDirectory()){
                    dirs.push(items[i]);
                }
                else{files.push(items[i])}
            }
        }
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            files: files,
            dirs: dirs
        }));
    });
```

In order to run both the ReactJS and the NodeJS on the same port, I built the ReactJS and added it to the NodeJS server by putting the build file into the same folder as the NodeJS file and adding `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));` to the NodeJS.

I hope this is helpful to anyone else facing a similar issue.